# Webpack will not bundle my files in the right public directory

Tags: webpack, bundle

Hi am working with a node.js/react/webpack application. The files should be compiled into a static `public` folder directory once the app is build. However, this does not happen and everything remains at the root level (index.html and bundle.js)

In the root I  have a server.js with the following:

```
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(5000, 'localhost', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Listening at localhost:5000');
});
```

I then have a `scripts`folder where my App.js and all the key imported scripts and css live. My package.json include the start/build scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.production.js",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --ignore-path .gitignore --format=node_modules/eslint-formatter-pretty . *.js",
    "test": "npm run lint"
  }
```

Updated. No errors, bundle.js and index.html load in public directory but page is blank.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    './scripts/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path:path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'scripts'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css'],
        include: __dirname + '/scripts'
      }

    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};
```

It renders the outlying HTML code but not the

```
render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

from scripts/index.js. I have included `import { render } from 'react-dom';`

In the console I get the following issue:

```
 Target container is not a DOM element
```

the index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/bundle.js"></script></body>
  <body>
</html>
```

Comment: path: __dirname,, Append the public folder here to output your files .. PublicPath is just a virtual path used to link the bundle CSS, js in index html

Comment: Yes, I was searching about this. I updated webpack wtih copy-webpack-plugin but there is still nothing in the public directory.

Comment: You don't need copy-webpack-plugin. What I m saying is that just alter your output path : from __dirname to new output folder.

Comment: Thanks but that only outputs the bundle.js folder. How do I get it to move both bundle and index.html into that for deployment?

Comment: Ohh.. so basically you wanted to output your both bundle.js and index.js in output folder ? Bit confused on your requirement

Comment: That's correct, I want to be in the postion of having PUBLIC as a deployment bundle so I don't need any other files when putting it on the server

Answer (score 0):

CopyWebpackPlugin is not the right choice your requirement i.e. to copy your index.html to your build folder.

You can use **HtmlWebpackPlugin** for that with further flexible options :

https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin

> This is a webpack plugin that simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles. You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for you, supply your own template using lodash templates or use your own loader.

The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags. Just add the plugin to your webpack config as follows:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  .....
  .....
  .....
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
 ]
};
```

This will generate a file dist/index.html containing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index_bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is module.exports into this and how can I decide what goes inside the html file?

Comment: @HGB : Check now, I hve updated the solution.
Also, you can put your content in your index file.

Comment: Hi, I also updated my code above but am still getting errors: `var webpackConfig = {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Updated again. No need for the var declaratin before entry and index.html and bundle.js are in the public folder, however nothing loads even if bundle.js is properly being requested. The console tells me `Target container is not a DOM element.`. Something obviously doesn't work with the files being in this public directory.